# OneUI Placebar Container Node expand on hover

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Is it possible to have the place bar container node expand the children on hover rather than on click? I looked through all of the properties and did not see anything obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jim, 
the Oneui definition does not recommend Placebar hover actions. However there is a OneUI "MaxiMenu" (forgot the exact name) that might open on hover. You can check it's documentation. In General you need to use an XSP.onLoad to add an event listener to the HTML

Comment: Thanks for the info. I dig a bit more digging based on your answer and found out it is the "Mega Menu" in OneUI V3. I haven't tried it yet, but you can read about it here http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/3.0/docPublic/components/megaMenu.htm